# Is there a byte equivalent of the 'stringify' macro?

Tags: macros, rust

Rust has a [`stringify!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.stringify.html) macro to get an expression as a string.
Is there a way to get the equivalent functionality that outputs bytes instead?

As if the expression were written as a byte string literal, e.g.: `b"some text"`.

---

The reason to use a macro instead of `str.as_bytes()` is that conversion functions can't be used to construct `const` values.[See this question for why you might want to use this macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199727).

Comment: Why not just use `str.as_bytes()` to convert the result?

Comment: Conversion functions can't be used for constructing `const` values at the moment.

Comment: Might be able to work around this with the `lazy_static` crate to create a "const".

Answer (score 4):

If you are using nightly Rust (since 1.28.0-nightly, 2018-05-23), you may enable the `const_str_as_bytes` feature which turns `as_bytes()` into a `const` function.

```
#![feature(const_str_as_bytes)]

fn main() {
    const AAA: &[u8] = stringify!(aaa).as_bytes();
    println!("{:?}", AAA);  // [97, 97, 97]
}
```

([Demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d476cc8505d4de98aa75e8fa097b869b&version=nightly&mode=release))

Comment: It is also possible to write a proc-macro-hack like [bytify](https://github.com/mahou-shoujo/bytify-rs) which works on stable Rust 1.15.0+, but the steps are quite tedious and it's better to let whoever that written the package to submit the answer.

Comment: [`str::as_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_bytes) is `const` since 1.32.0.