# How to construct const integers from literal byte expressions?

Tags: rust, byte, constants, data-conversion

Is there a way to construct a `const` integer from a literal byte expression, either using a byte string or a macro which constructs the integer?

For example:

```
const MY_ID:   u16 = u16_code!(ID);
const MY_WORD: u32 = u32_code!(WORD);
const MY_LONG: u64 = u64_code!(LONGWORD);
```

Or something similar, passing in `b"ID"` instead of `ID`? *****

It should fail to compile when the wrong number of characters are passed too, something I couldn't figure out how to achieve when using bit-shifting on a literal byte string.

---

Here's a simple example that works on a basic level, but fails to ensure correctly sized arguments.

```
// const MY_ID: u16 = u16_code!(b"ID");
#[cfg(target_endian = "little")]
macro_rules! u16_code {
    ($w:expr) => { ((($w[0] as u16) <<  0) | (($w[1] as u16) <<  8)) }
}
#[cfg(target_endian = "big")]
macro_rules! u16_code {
    ($w:expr) => { ((($w[1] as u16) <<  0) | (($w[0] as u16) <<  8)) }
}
```

---

***** See related question: [Is there a byte equivalent of the 'stringify' macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42199312)

Comment: *I couldn't figure out how to achieve when using bit-shifting on a literal byte string*. Please provide such previous work when you ask a question

Comment: @ker, I started doing this but then had one of these questions flagged to move to "code-review", I find if I post example code the answers focus too much on picking apart naive code, instead of whats possible, especially when my approach may be wrong in the first place. Nevertheless I don't mind to post examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can build a macro for each type by indexing into the array and bitshifting the parts to the correct position. An example expression for your u16 is

```
((b"ID"[0] as u16) << 8) | (b"ID"[1] as u16)
```

You can replace the `b"ID"` by a macro replacement `$e` which comes from a `$e:expr`.

To achieve the length check, you can insert a useless `*$e as [u8; 2]`, which will fail to compile if the types don't match.

Comment: Unfortunately constants created using this method can't be used as values in match statements (Causes error E0080, see note in my own answer).

Comment: correct, that is a nightly feature that has been around for a while. You can open an RFC to make it stable.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @ker's suggestion, here are portable macros that create constant identifiers based on fixed size byte strings:

**Warning:** there are some limitations on these constants that aren't immediately obvious (see notes below).

The following macros support:

```
const MY_ID:   u16 = u16_code!(b"ID");
const MY_WORD: u32 = u32_code!(b"WORD");
const MY_LONG: u64 = u64_code!(b"LONGWORD");
```

Implementation:

```
#[cfg(target_endian = "little")]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! u16_code {
    ($w:expr) => {
        ((($w[0] as u16) <<  0) |
         (($w[1] as u16) <<  8) |
         ((*$w as [u8; 2])[0] as u16 * 0))
    }
}
#[cfg(target_endian = "big")]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! u16_code {
    ($w:expr) => {
        ((($w[1] as u16) <<  0) |
         (($w[0] as u16) <<  8) |
         ((*$w as [u8; 2])[0] as u16 * 0))
    }
}

#[cfg(target_endian = "little")]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! u32_code {
    ($w:expr) => {
        ((($w[0] as u32) <<  0) |
         (($w[1] as u32) <<  8) |
         (($w[2] as u32) << 16) |
         (($w[3] as u32) << 24) |
         ((*$w as [u8; 4])[0] as u32 * 0))
    }
}
#[cfg(target_endian = "big")]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! u32_code {
    ($w:expr) => {
        ((($w[3] as u32) <<  0) |
         (($w[2] as u32) <<  8) |
         (($w[1] as u32) << 16) |
         (($w[0] as u32) << 24) |
         ((*$w as [u8; 4])[0] as u32 * 0))
    }
}

#[cfg(target_endian = "little")]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! u64_code {
    ($w:expr) => {
        ((($w[0] as u64) <<  0) |
         (($w[1] as u64) <<  8) |
         (($w[2] as u64) << 16) |
         (($w[3] as u64) << 24) |
         (($w[4] as u64) << 32) |
         (($w[5] as u64) << 40) |
         (($w[6] as u64) << 48) |
         (($w[7] as u64) << 56) |
         ((*$w as [u8; 8])[0] as u64 * 0))
    }
}
#[cfg(target_endian = "big")]
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! u64_code {
    ($w:expr) => {
        ((($w[7] as u64) <<  0) |
         (($w[6] as u64) <<  8) |
         (($w[5] as u64) << 16) |
         (($w[4] as u64) << 24) |
         (($w[3] as u64) << 32) |
         (($w[2] as u64) << 40) |
         (($w[1] as u64) << 48) |
         (($w[0] as u64) << 56) |
         ((*$w as [u8; 8])[0] as u64 * 0))
    }
}
```

---

**Note 1)** the line that checks the size needed to be or'd with the constant because separate statements aren't supported in constant expressions (`E0016`).

I'd also have preferred to use `if cfg!(target_endian = "big")` within the one macro, but the same limitation for constants prevents it.

**Note 2)** There is potentially a problem using these macros for non-constant input, where the argument could be instantiated for every byte *(and possibly the sanity check for size)*. I looked into assigning a variable, but this causes error `E0016` too.

**Note 3)** While Rust allows these values to be declared as `const` they can't be used in `match` statements.

eg:

```
error[E0080]: constant evaluation error
   --> src/mod.rs:112:23
    |
112 | const MY_DATA: u32 = u32_code!(b"DATA");
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the index operation on const values is unstable
    |
note: for pattern here
   --> src/mod.rs:224:13
    |
224 |             MY_DATA => {
    |             ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Maybe a `match` expression instead of a `let` statement would do the trick? `match $w { w => .. }`

Comment: As with nearly all clever tricks in this context, it gives: `error[E0016]: blocks in constants are limited to items and tail expressions`.

Comment: That's if you wrap the `match` in a block. Otherwise, you get... an internal compiler error (oops!). Then the only solution I can think of is a `const fn` (which is an unstable feature), to bind the expression to an argument (and a `const fn` also gives you type checking).

Answer (score 0):

With newer Rust versions, you can just do:

```rust
const IMA4_FOURCC: u32 = u32::from_be_bytes(*b"ima4");
```

It's very useful when dealing with FourCCs.

You can wrap it in a macro if you want to.